# antenna multicoupling connecting lines

Tags: rf, antenna

I'm trying to find information about how to properly calculate the connecting coax length in a string of cavity filters for a VHF multicoupler.

I figure it should be something like a 1/4 wave length of the frequency but I can't seem to find any definitive documentation.

Can someone point me in he correct direction?

Comment: It's all well known. Did you read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer ?

Answer (score 1):

It really shouldn't matter all that much if the cavities are impedance-matched to the coax; varying the length would only vary the relative phasing of the fields in successive cavities (does this matter?).

However, if the cavities are not matched to the coax (or if you're not sure that they are), it would be wise to use cables that are multiples of 1/2 of the electrical wavelength long, because whatever impedance is presented at one end of such a cable will be "reflected" at the other end.

Comment: It does make some difference.  The line connections between filter chain #1 and filter chain#2 that pull signal off the same antenna need to be at an electrical distance apart that you match or null the impedance at the end of the array to the 1/4 or 1/2 wavelength of he first frequency being pulled.  I need a diagram to help make sense... sorry if I'm not explaining myself very well.